# Trying to use filter function on strings

Tags: python-3.x

i have the following function and I am trying to make a list containing the 'tweet numbers' of tweets done by DanClark . I am splitting the strings and trying to use the filter function to produce it. I am trying to avoid explicit recursion. i keep getting the following error " 'str' object is not callable" when i try to run "search_tweets(tweets, "DanClark")"

```
tweet1 = "#1::@DanClark::The party was amazing" 
tweet19 = "#19::@NatalyS::Avoid 401 Toronto area at this time" 
tweet50 = "#50::@CBCNews::How Canadian captain gave her team a speech" 
tweet14 = "#14::@DanClark::The food was good"
tweet15 = "#15::@DaveLin::Lucky you DanClark"
tweets =   [tweet1, tweet19, tweet50, tweet14, tweet15]

def separator(tweets, item1, item2, tweeter):

part1 = (tweets[item1].split('::'))
part2 = part1[item2]
part3 = part2[1:]

  if part3 == tweeter:
      return (part1[0])[1:]
  else:
      return []

def search_tweets(tweets, tweeter):
  return list(filter((separator(tweets, 0, 1, tweeter)), tweets))
```

Comment: Why would u even use filter ?

Comment: i was told not to use explicit recursion. so i tried doing it with filter.

Comment: why even use recursion, there is no need for recursion

Comment: its a practise question for an exam. the restriction is that i cannot use explicit recursion or loops, only abstract list functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really insist to do it without explicit loops, list comprehensions or anything of that sort, you can map each element of your list to a searching function, and then filter out empty results. Something like:

```
def search_tweets(tweets, author):

    def search_tweet(tweet):
        tweet_fields = tweet.split('::', 2)
        return tweet_fields[0][1:] if tweet_fields[1][1:] == author else None

    return list(filter(None, map(search_tweet, tweets)))
```

Then if you provide it your data and call it with the intended author, you'll get the expected result:

```
tweet1 = "#1::@DanClark::The party was amazing"
tweet19 = "#19::@NatalyS::Avoid 401 Toronto area at this time"
tweet50 = "#50::@CBCNews::How Canadian captain gave her team a speech"
tweet14 = "#14::@DanClark::The food was good"
tweet15 = "#15::@DaveLin::Lucky you DanClark"
tweets = [tweet1, tweet19, tweet50, tweet14, tweet15]

print(search_tweets(tweets, "DanClark"))
# prints: ['1', '14']
```

Btw. (opinion time) this is a bone-headed way to do it, but whatever... I've heard idiot teachers and interviewers ask for even more ridiculous things.

Answer (score 0):

I believe filter expects the first argument to be a function whereas you are giving it the return value of your call to separator.

From python docs:

Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator expression (item for item in iterable if function(item))

Answer (score 0):

```
tweet1 = "#1::@DanClark::The party was amazing" 
tweet19 = "#19::@NatalyS::Avoid 401 Toronto area at this time" 
tweet50 = "#50::@CBCNews::How Canadian captain gave her team a speech" 
tweet14 = "#14::@DanClark::The food was good"
tweet15 = "#15::@DaveLin::Lucky you DanClark"
tweets = [tweet1, tweet19, tweet50, tweet14, tweet15]

def numbers_of_tweets_done_by(who):
    r_list = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        t_info = tweet.split('::')
        if t_info[1] == who:
           r_list.append(int(t_info[0][1:]))
    return r_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(numbers_of_tweets_done_by('@DanClark'))

#Prints [1,14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> tweet1 = "#1::@DanClark::The party was amazing" 
>>> tweet19 = "#19::@NatalyS::Avoid 401 Toronto area at this time" 
>>> tweet50 = "#50::@CBCNews::How Canadian captain gave her team a speech" 
>>> tweet14 = "#14::@DanClark::The food was good"
>>> tweet15 = "#15::@DaveLin::Lucky you DanClark"
>>> tweets =   [tweet1, tweet19, tweet50, tweet14, tweet15]
```

You can use `filter` to search the list `tweets` for tweets by the first element like so:

```
>>> tweeter = '#50'
>>> list(filter(lambda s: s.partition('::')[0]==tweeter, tweets))
['#50::@CBCNews::How Canadian captain gave her team a speech']
```

Or the second element:

```
>>> tweeter = '@DanClark'
>>> list(filter(lambda s: s.split('::')[1]==tweeter, tweets))
['#1::@DanClark::The party was amazing', '#14::@DanClark::The food was good']
```

Then if you just want the numbers corresponding to Dan's tweets:

```
>>> [e.partition('::')[0] for e in filter(lambda s: s.split('::')[1]==tweeter, tweets)]
['#1', '#14']
```